# What logic system do you use for day-to-day thinking and why?

Tags: logic

I'm studying various logic systems and I'm wondering what logic systems that you folks use on a day-to-day basis? That is, in your daily lives, what logic system do you use?

Comment: See SEP's entry on [defeasible reasoning](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-defeasible/) and WP's entry on [informal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_logic).

Comment: @JD Thanks JD. I assumed that most people used different ways of thinking. Then I could figure out which one works best for me.

Comment: If you look at philosophy choices for logic you will see distinctions between math and philosophy. I will mention logic books by Irving Copi and Cohen plus the Patrick Hurley books. Each of the names I mentioned have a introductory logic book.  Copi and Cohen are authors of one introductory logic book. These books contain  information about Aristotelian logic as well as Mathematical logic. You will see some terminology like tautology is different, contradictory is different, contrapositive is different, etc. When I say different I mean the context being used. It is certainly NOT math like.

Comment: In everyday life people do not use logical systems, they reason intuitively. Scholastics called the skill *logica utens*, logic-in-use. Logical systems are meant to  formalize some segments of such reasoning and/or develop specialized forms of reasoning for some particular application. Most of mathematics adopts classical first order logic, for example, deontic logic formalizes reasoning about obligations and permissions, epistemic logic about what is known, etc.

Comment: Before this question is closed, know that formal logic is fascinating, but it's not highly useful in real life. If you want to understand what informal logic is about, start with Toulmin's [Uses of Argument](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Uses_of_Argument/8UYgegaB1S0C?hl=en&gbpv=0). It's a tough read, but it goes to show how formal logic fails.

Comment: No "system" at all.

Comment: I don’t think this question deserves to be marked down three points because I think a lot of students of logic are led to ask this very question. So I applaud the OP for asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

As a recovering ex-engineer, I take an approach rooted in realism and guided by mathematical logic when solving problems around the house, my car, my bass guitar amplifier, or my motorcycle. This is a valid approach when the human element in the problem definition is zero, or nearly so.

It is not a valid approach when the human element is dominant- when attempting to solve problems related to for example my divorce, the demise of my career, the death of my parents, my relationships with my adult children, or the outcomes of elections.

Comment: Thanks Neils. I'm an advocate of mathematical logic myself, that's the system I'll be using.

Comment: just remember, don't apply it to understanding human behavior!